# Creating a "Mobile Adapter" for Visual Web parts in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: mobile, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, adapter

I've followed [this guide](http://edwin.vriethoff.net/2010/01/17/sharepoint-2010-mobile-web-part-development/) on how to create mobile web parts in Sharepoint 2010, but no content is listed when I access the page with a mobile device, or use the "/m"-url. Are there any other sources on how to create a mobile adapter for visual web parts for Sharepoint 2010?

My adapter-class looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.MobileControls;

namespace MyProject.MyOrderList
{
   public class MyOrderListMobileAdapter : WebPartMobileAdapter
   {
    protected override void CreateControlsForDetailView()
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.MobileControls.SPMobileLabel lblHello = new Microsoft.SharePoint.MobileControls.SPMobileLabel();
        lblHello.Text = "Hello World. This is the Mobile version of the SharePoint web part.";
        Controls.Add(lblHello);                       
    }
  }
}
```

I've also added an entry to the "controlAdapters" in the "compat.browser"-file:

```
<adapter controlType="MyProject.MyOrderList, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be5098001a913377" 
                 adapterType="MyProject.MyOrderList.MyOrderListMobileAdapter, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be5098001a913377" />
```

The safecontrol-entry looks like this:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be5098001a913377" Namespace="MyProject.MyOrderList" TypeName="*" Safe="True" SafeAgainstScript="False" />
```

Basicly I want to just create a simplified version of my visual web part without having to create a whole new web part that's just for mobile access, which is what I should be able to accomplish this adapter-method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:
Creating a Mobile Adapter for SharePoint 2010
http://allthingsdotnet.net/?p=603

They won't let me post more than one hyperlink, so for the next subject:

Custom VWP Not Visible in Mobile Mode 
use the same as above, with this as the querystring - - ?p=518

Also, there's a new application that helps create the correct syntax for the Safe Control section in the Web.Config and the Compat.Browser entry:
Mobile Adapter Tool:

ma.augustwind.com

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN hands on lab was pretty helpful in getting mobile web parts going.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointandwindowsphone7trainingcourse_creatingmobilewebpartslab_topic2